# Difference between soft k-means and fuzzy c-means

Tags: clustering

I often see in various tutorials and webpages that explains fuzzy c-means clustering and soft k-means clustering. But i was not able to find any material which differentiates them.

Is it that both fuzzy c-means and soft k-means clustering are same or different?

Answer (score 2):

The only reference I know about soft k-means is actually triangle k-means as used in [Analysis of Single Layer Unsupervised Feature Learning](http://www.eecs.umich.edu/~honglak/aistats11-AnalysisSingleLayerUnsupervisedFeatureLearning.pdf). The idea is to use sums of 'one of k' vectors as features for images.

Here, a rolling window is used on image patches. Each patch is then assigned to one of k clusters and this is represented as a 'one of k' vector. The sum of all those vectors then gives a global descriptor for the image.

An extension of this, which is working really well, is to not use one of k vectors, but the actual distances to the centroids instead. As an additional step, all distances which are higher than the mean distance are set to zero.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO they are two different name for the same thing..

Comment: Any justification to add? (in order to avoid the one-liner answer badge :)

Comment: here you go:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345903/whats-is-the-difference-between-k-means-and-fuzzy-c-means-objective-function